# Objective C: How to make background color of UITableView Consistent

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have been trying to set the background color of my table view but am facing an issue

This is what I am trying to do.

```
//Set background color of table view (translucent)
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.2 blue:0.5 alpha:0.7];

//Set frame for tableview
[self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-self.picker.frame.size.height)];
```

After setting the table cells, I saw that there is an inconsistency in the alpha level around the table view cell (see screenshot below)

[image: tableView BackgroundColor]

Is there anyway to make the color / alpha level consistent for the background?
(Note: I am not setting a background image, only color and alpha level)

Thanks!

Zhen Hoe

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I recently ran into this problem myself and think I found the solution

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.2 blue:0.5 alpha:0.7];
```

Give that a shot, might need some massaging for your specific case (looks like you have some picture behind that translucent blue too).

Comment: Yup, thanks for the solution. I needed to add another parent view for the tableview before I can implement your solution. But it works fine for me. Thanks!

Comment: The solution is to set the background to clearColor in code and not with IB. http://www.martianstorm.com/wordpress/?p=48

Answer (score 5):

You need to make the background of the UITableView clear as well as set Opaque to `FALSE`

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
[self.tableView setOpaque: NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do are 2 things:

E.g. A view has a table view in it.
In the `XIB` file set the background of the `UITableView` to clear color.
Set the background of the container view of the table view to the image you want.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"app_background.png"]];
```

If the ViewController is actually a `TableViewController` then set:

```
self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"app_background.png"]];
```

You can set the row background with inside the table view delegate (the view or tableview controller)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if ([indexPath row] % 2 == 0) {//248 G:192 B:100


[cell setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
} else {
   [cell setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xyz.png"]]];

  }
}
```